# npm start command not working, when I try to run my React application

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, npm-start

React is installed properly and everything else works, except when I try to run "npm start" in the terminal, it gives me the following error.

[image: Picture of the error]

Here's my package.json code:

```
        {
      "name": "r3-ui",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
        "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Comment: delete your node_modules and do npm install and try...if still doesn't work then share your package.json file

Comment: Nope it still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `&` when naming the directory on Windows. Rename `UI & Web Design` into `UI_Web_Design`. Anything after the `&` is treated as a command.

After changing the name of the directory run `npm start`.